# why the output is different from the value of variable after showing using plt.imshow?

Tags: python, keras

I have a variable with shape (1,28,28,1) and all of its values are `1`, but when I show it with `plt.imshow(intermediate.reshape(28,28), cmap='gray')` it shows a black image, though it should be white. When I check the variable explorer, all values are indeed `1`.

Why does this happen? Can I be sure the correct value will be passed on to the rest of my code? Why does it show a black image in the output?

this the output of w_test I put the code in the comment.
[image]

Comment: why should it be white?

Comment: Not knowing anything about this technology, my big question is if your line of code in your question is showing how you "just show it", and you're wondering why that changes something, what role might the `intermediate.reshape( 28,28)` part of that line play?  That line in full sure seems to be manipulating something rather than just displaying it.  This may be a naive observation.  It just has me curious at least.

Comment: @Steve the reshape isn't the issue. It just moves things around in memory without changing the values.

Comment: @PaulH, ok, thanks.  I figured that was too blatant a feature to likely be the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Grayscale is typically 8 bits, ranging in value from 0-255. Thus, a grayscale color of `1` is pretty close to black (which is `0`). White is actually `255`.

Try multiplying the whole array by `255` and you should get white.

Something like:

`intermediate = intermediate*255`

Your values are fine, if a value of `1` is what you want. If you want a black or white image, use values of `0` for black and `255` for white.

Comment: are you sure about the problem? because when I produce an image with random value 0 and 1 and then show it, I see an image that 1's are white w_test = np.random.randint(2,size=(1,4,4))
w_test=w_test.astype(np.float32)
w_test=w_test.reshape((1,4,4,1))